# Can conditional type in typescript depend on a value of itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can I implement such type in typescript?

```
type Someone = {
  who: string;
}

type Someone = Someone.who === "me" ? Someone & Me : Someone;
```

Comment: The example doesn't make sense because a compile time type cannot depend on a runtime value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) could work:

```js
type Me = {
  who: 'me',
  secret: string;
}

type Other = {
  who: 'other',
}

type Someone = Me | Other;
```

Comment: damn, that actually works for me and looks rly simple) thanks, just need to rewrote all interfaces to types now because this thing doesn't work with interfaces

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do so with the help of [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

Below is a minimally working example:

```
type Someone<T extends string> = {
    who: T;
}

type Me = {
    me: boolean;
}

type Thisone<T extends string> = T extends 'me' ? Someone<T> & Me : Someone<T>;

function whoami<T extends string>(who: T) {
    return {
        who,
        me: who === 'me' ? true : undefined
    } as Thisone<T>
}

const a = whoami('you');
const b = whoami('me');

a.who;  // ok
a.me;   // error

b.who;  // ok
b.me;   // ok
```

[Demo in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwnAdhAPAFShAHsCFAEwGcoTgAnASxQHMA+KAXigG8BYAKAEgB3ABZwAXFEwBubgF9u3UJCgBZaK068kogEZw4AGwgBDFJK4yuc8NEwDqJVBmx4CxMhRr0mrR-kKkoAciR-KAB+WERkNCwmADIlaFF4JHtok24AMwBXFABjYGpUKEE4AwRqLBwfF3IqWkYACmLRTABKdm4eSghgTMoUdt5+IQAaDp4NIqEWZlZAiGCwqkyEqGyiCHTaCCIOqSgDMmtbFMwGaVkuHNQKfZZJkrL6-xA4TP8WkyuUG8074tLqE8gh8LgYAHTFcQ8AD00KgcAA1txwUhxFB0bCcJRKHBKBdNBChFDMYjuATUTC4YigA).

Comment: i think in your example it is required to specify "T" parameter, i would like it to take a value automatically e.g
```
const a: Someone = { who: "me", me: true } // ok
const b: Someone = { who: "you", me: true } // error
```

Comment: @ZhenyaUsenko that is impossible because that would mean depending on a runtime value. Type checking only happens in the compile time, which is why you need to set the type constraint with `T`.

Comment: btw, the answer above works for me, thanks for the help anyways